# JSON encoding Python list of classes

Tags: python, json, class

I've read through a few questions that address something similar, but wanted to ask about this.

I have two Python classes, simplified here:

```
class Service:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ServiceName = None
        self.ServiceExpDate = None

class Provision:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = None
        self.Type = None
        self.Services = [] # a list of Service objects
```

When I go to JSON encode an instance of the Provision class:

```
jsonProvision = json.dumps(provision.__dict__)
```

I get the correct output if I don't have any Services, but if it tries to serialize the Service class I get:

```
TypeError: <common.Service instance at 0x123d7e8> is not JSON serializable
```

Do I need to write a JSON encoder to handle this directly, or is there a better way to serialize the Service class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write an encoder that takes care of your classes, that's the way `json` module is meant to be used/extended.

Your attempt to encode the `__dict__` of your `Provision` class instances may work now but is really not future proof if you class evolves.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a function to encode your custom classes as the `default` parameter to `json.dumps()`.  Example code for the classes:

```py
import json

class JSONEncodable(object):
    def json(self):
        return vars(self)

class Service(JSONEncodable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ServiceName = None
        self.ServiceExpDate = None

class Provision(JSONEncodable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = None
        self.Type = None
        self.Services = [] # a list of Service objects
```

Example usage:

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> p = Provision()
>>> p.Services.append(Service())
>>> print json.dumps(p, default=methodcaller("json"))
{"Services": [{"ServiceName": null, "ServiceExpDate": null}], "Type": null, "ID": null}
```

You could also use `default=attrgetter("__dict__")` to avoid the need for a `json()` method on every class, but the above approach is more flexible.